# Error connecting to remote gdbserver through gdb

Tags: c++, docker, gdb, fastcgi, gdbserver

I have a docker container running with -p 2000:2000, which is running a gdbserver on port 2000.

When trying to connect from my host machine through gdb I get the following:

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:2000
Remote debugging using localhost:2000
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
warning: unrecognized item "timeout" in "qSupported" response
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Remote replied unexpectedly to 'vMustReplyEmpty': timeout
```

The application running in the docker container is written in C++, behind a fcgi (`gdbserver :2000 spawn-fcgi -p 8000 -n ./myBinary`)

Host

- OS: osx
- gdb version: 8.0.1 (installed with --with-all-targets)

Container

- OS: ubuntu 14.04
- gdb version: 7.7.1

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i meet the same question ，when i run my qemu ，and i want connect gdb with qemu inner gdbserver.
i do the  follow job:

1. run qemu in system mode.
2. run gdbserver inside qemu
3. run gdb in  Host computer and connect gdbservr inside gdb.

the software version are below:

```
QEMU emulator version 2.12.92
gdb 7.11.1
GNU gdbserver (GDB) 7.8
```

at first i cannot connect gdbserver,the error is

```
(gdb) target remote 192.168.240.136:1234
Remote debugging using 192.168.240.136:1234
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
warning: unrecognized item "timeout" in "qSupported" response
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Remote replied unexpectedly to 'vMustReplyEmpty': timeout
```

i solve the problem by **change to high level kernel** when start start qemu. from **vmlinux-2.6.32-5-4kc-malta**  to **vmlinux-3.2.0-4-4kc-malta**,then the command start qemu changed to below:

```
sudo qemu-system-mips -M malta \
-kernel vmlinux-3.2.0-4-4kc-malta \
-hda debian_squeeze_mips_standard.qcow2 \
-append "root=/dev/sda1 console=tty0" \
-net nic,macaddr=00:16:3e:00:01:01 \
-net tap \
-nographic
```

then the error was solved ,i can connect gdbserver with gdb.

the possible solve ways also include

- [bash setting
  conflict](https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion/issues/281)
- [serial setting error](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1063214/porting-kgdb-error-need-help-/?offset=2)